# Asymptotics of Product of consecutive primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am looking for the asymptotic growth of product of consecutive primes. Is there anything that is known about this growth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Denote by $$\Pi(x)=\prod_{p\leqslant x}p,$$ thus
$$\log\Pi(x)=\sum_{p\leqslant x}\log p:=\theta(x)\sim x,$$ which is known as the Prime Number Theorem. You may find further information in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem

Answer (score 12):

I think you're asking about the [primorial function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) $n\sharp$, the product of all the primes less than or equal to $n$. This satisfies $ n \sharp = \exp( n(1+o(1)) ) $.

Comment: Are sharper bounds known?  This is actually a pretty bad estimate for n small (less than, say, a billion).

Comment: @Charles: If you assume the Riemann Hypothesis, you get roughly $\exp(n+O(\sqrt{n}))$

Comment: @Charles: Why do you say it is bad? Up to the (very) small bound of 350000 I find results such as [ 82619, .99728] [119549, .99537] [155893, .99855] [302831, .99671] [338477, .99898] meaning that at the prime n=82619 it is about $\exp( 0.99728n )$. etc. After a relatively large prime gap the exponent will be lower and after a relatively prime dense interval it will be higher.

Comment: @Aaron Meyerowitz: exp(1e6)/1e6# is about 2e658. It's not so much that I mind being off by a factor of googol^6, but I wanted to know if more asymptotic terms were known.

Comment: @Charles OK so you are telling me that $10^6 \sharp$ is about $exp(10^6\cdot 0.99934)$. Working from that, I then get [1090697, .9991] ,[1195247, 1.00026] and [1243337, .99948]. I can't vouch for all those decimal places but the relative fluctuations should be pretty accurate. I can't imagine that asymptotic terms are going to account for fluctuations like that. The best you should expect is to get $\ln(n \sharp)$ about right and I think the answers above do that. 

Comment: @Aaron Meyerowitz: I don't agree with your numbers; I get [1090697, .9983], [1195247, .99954], [1243337, .99878].

Comment: Further, I don't see any terms giving a multiplier of more than 1 (though I imagine they exist, just like Skewes' number); up to 10 million the largest value I find is 0.999812981 at 7105253.

Comment: I agree with your numbers and your Skewes conjecture (although that is a pure guess and I don't know if one has to go to huge numbers). I only said that my fluctations were pretty accurate and we agree that they are roughly +0.0011 then -.0008. I was working off your 2e658 figure at the time so my absolute numbers were not more accurate than that.

Answer (score 5):

You can also prove that $$\displaystyle\lim_n\left(\prod_1^n p_i\right)^{1/p_n} = e$$

(where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime number and $e$ is Euler's exponential number)